# How to have when logged in users click link they get sent to one page, and when logged out users click link they get sent to a different page?

Tags: wordpress, authentication, hyperlink, login-control

On my Wordpress website I have a page that I only want logged in users to access (e.g. "www.domain.com/logged-in-user-page") and a page that I only want logged out users to access ("www.domain.com/logged-out-user-page"). How can I have it so that if a logged in user types in the domain for the logged out page, they are directed to the logged in page and vice versa. Or clicks on a link and is taken to the correct page whether they are logged in or out.

I've already managed to show and hide the correct page in my navbar menu, but also need to have the redirect when they click on a link I have on my homepage or type in the wrong domain in the address bar. I have seen examples of php script but just can't figure it out. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(is_user_logged_in()) {
  // Redirect to another page
  header("Location: http://www.example.com/logged-in-page");
} else {
  // Display something else
  header("Location: http://www.example.com/logged-out-page");
}
exit;
```

For security purposes, you have to add checks to both pages, too, or at least to the logged-in-page:

```
if(!is_user_logged_in()) {
  header("Location: http://www.example.com/logged-out-page");
  exit;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I'm not sure if I explained my issue clearly. To clarify, I have a link on my homepage that says "Book Now". And I'd like it when logged in users click that link, they're taken to the "www.domain.com/logged-in-user-book-now" page. And when logged out users click it, they are taken to the "www.domain.com/logged-out-user-book-now" page. I already have it so that when users log in they're automatically directed to the "logged in" page, but I need to have this functionality when clicking my "Book Now" link on my homepage.

Comment: I put in the code you provided shown below. But when I go to my domain, it says "this web page has a redirect loop":   <?php if(is_user_logged_in()) {
  // Redirect to another page
  header("Location: http://www.example.com/logged-in-page");
} else {
  // Display something else
  header("Location: http://www.example.com/logged-out-page");
}
exit;  ?>

Comment: Just put that first code snippet into a file like `example.com/book-now` and let that file redirect to those other files. You can then link to `book-now` and users will get redirected to `logged-in-page` or `logged-out-page`.

Comment: I have copy/pasted your first snippet into my custom functions (and replaced the domains with the logged in user domain and logged out user domain) but site gives redirect loop error. Is this not where I should put the code? What do you mean put it into a file?    Thanks

Comment: If it is a Wordpress site, how do you "create" new pages? How do you insert the PHP code? With files or with a plugin? Remove redirect code from the two other files (logged-in/out) and the loop should disappear.

Comment: Oh I see. Yes, it is most likely my login/logout plugin that causes the loop. Thank you very much for your help!